# rasa chatbot and mattermost integration process

Tags: rasa, mattermost

I tried to integrate the rasa chatbot server with mattermost bot but unable to complete.

An bot from the mattermost can interact the the rasa ai model

added this to my crediantials.yaml file
mattermost:
url: “http://localhost:8065/api/v4”
token: “dajx3cuyp7bwf8648d1zatzpm” “this is the access token of bot”
webhook_url: “http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook”

Comment: Resolved it. Successfully connected my rasa AI with the Mattermost Bot.